# Fetch Student object from List<Student> with matching name without iterating (Java)

Tags: java, list, collections

I have a `List<Student>` and `String firstName="George"`. I want to extract Student object from List matching with `"George"` without iterating list. Is it possible?

May be if some method override required or anything to make it work.

```
public Class Student {
     private String firstName;
     private String lastName;
     private String class;

     // getter, setter methods goes here....
}
```

Please help me thanks.

Comment: Use a `Map`.  Anything else is a form of iteration in one manner or another

Comment: have you tried any thing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java List.contains(Object with field value equal to x)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852059/java-list-containsobject-with-field-value-equal-to-x)

Comment: @madprogrammer is right. You need a [Map<String, Student>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Comment: Not possible with `List`

Comment: If you want to avoid iterating and want to use a list you could implement a SortedList by extending AbstractList. Then update Student to implement comparable in such a way that George will be the first entry in a sorted collection. Or just use a Map

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. The LIST I got from SOAP request which I don't want to iterate. If I have  to build a map means I am iterating list rather I will do my lookup of required Student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Override the equal() method
Then create a Student object with firstname="George"
When you do it, you can use list.indexOf(Student_object) method to find out the position of that object and you can use list.get(index) to get Student object in the list

Comment: But you can't use `list.indexOf("George")` and internally, it's still a form of iteration

Comment: I mean creating new object Student and setFirstname is "George". And with this, at least we don't have to use loop

Comment: I know what you mean, but I'm reasonable certain it's not what the OP is looking for an internally, it's still using an iteration of some kind.  A `Map` would be the only solution which didn't require some form of iteration at one level of another, just saying ;)

Comment: This is how I have implemented, I thought without creating a new Student().setFirstName("George") I can achieve just by .contains("George"). Thank you for all responses.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8 then its possible using Stream and Lambda:-

```
List<Student> myStudent = studentsList.stream()
                                      .filter(s -> s.name.equals("George"))
                                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Technically, it's still a form of iteration

Comment: If we have a list there is no way other than iterating to search a particular object. What best we can do is make your searching efficient.

Comment: Then sort list and use some kind of binary search :P or use a `Map`

Answer (score 0):

No you have to iterate.. That's how list is. if you want retrieval to happen in O(1) then you need a map.

Answer (score 0):

You should have used hash map instead of List ,and add student name as a key with object.
HashMap=new HashMap;