# Get some value from List<Object> Java

Tags: java, string, list

I think it quite simple but I need one ways to solve it easy.

My problem is: I have list object Student include 100 objects

```
public class Student {

private String id;
private String name;
private int age;


public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
```

Now, I only want to get age of some student has name "ABC", "BCD", "DEF"

So I will do it:

```
Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> listSpecification = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("ABC", "BCD", "DEF"));
    for (Student stu : list<Student>) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listSpecification.size(); i++) {
            if (stu.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(listSpecification.get(i))) {
                data.put(pro.getName(), pro.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
```

But if I do it, I think it not good about performance. So anyone can help me another case ?

Comment: `listSpecification.contains(stu.getName())` - but you'll need to correct of case

Comment: Use below links. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852059/java-list-containsobject-with-field-value-equal-to-x

Comment: What's the variable `pro`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your algorithm has complexity O(m*n) where m is the number of students and n is the number of names. The suggestions to use streaming APIs or `Collection.contains` won't change that.

You can convert this to an O(m + n) algorithm by using a map from student name to `Student`:

```
Map<String, Student> studentsByName = new HashMap<>();
for (Student s : studentList) {
    studentsByName.put(s.getName().toLowerCase(), s);
}
```

That's an O(m) operation. Then you can iterate through all the names in the specification list, convert each to lower case, and pull out each student directly. This is an O(n) operation. There's a further efficiency in that you need do the first step only once if you need to process multiple specification lists for the same student list.

Comment: So, After I get map studentsByName. I must use 2 times for loop to get list student I want ? Is this correct or I miss something ?

Comment: @QuangTV - With this approach, you loop once through the students to build the map. Then you use a second loop to go through the names in the specification. You only need to loop one time (for each specification list) after mapping the students by name.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you have little choice, you need to compare each element in the `Student`'s `List` with each value in the `listSpecification` `List`.

You could use `listSpecification.contains(stu.getName())`, but you would need to guarantee the case requirements (maybe by making everything all upper case)

Another approach could be to make use of the new `Stream` API available in Java 8

```
List<String> listSpecification = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("ABC", "BCD", "DEF"));

List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
students.add(new Student("0", "ABC", 0));
students.add(new Student("1", "XYZ", 0));
students.add(new Student("2", "HIJ", 0));
students.add(new Student("3", "LMN", 0));
students.add(new Student("4", "OPQ", 0));
students.add(new Student("5", "BCD", 0));
students.add(new Student("6", "EFG", 0));
students.add(new Student("7", "HIJ", 0));
students.add(new Student("8", "DEF", 0));
students.add(new Student("9", "STY", 0));

List<Student> matches = students.stream().filter((Student t) -> listSpecification.contains(t.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(matches);
```

But, again, you would need to ensure that the `String` case matched (maybe by making the `listSpecification` all uppercase and using `t.getName().toUpperCase()`

Is it more efficient?  I'd doubt it, but you'd have to some serious comparisons to be sure.

Another technique might be to build a series of `Map`s which key certain values (like the name) to the instances of `Student`, as an example, but you'd need to provide more context to the overall problem to know if it was worth the effort or not

Comment: I will try and response soon. Thank you