# Update ArrayList, only if it equals a bookID?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have set up an ArrayList of type book for my library application. The current feature I am trying to implement is editing the details of a book. I have a variable called `bookID` so when I call this method through the ArrayList it will be `newBook.get(index).getBookID();`. And with this information I would like to check, and do the following things:

- There exists an element of the array with this ID
- Update the existing title with a new title

Problems I am being faced with:

- Looping through to get the index where the ID exists
- Updating the existing title, and replacing it with a new title

What I have came up with so far:

```
    // Editing book in ArrayList
public void editBook(){
    System.out.println("==============================");
    // Ensuring array has at least one book
    if(newBook.size() > 0){
        // Get which part, and book the user would like to edits
        System.out.print("Enter Book ID to begin editing: ");
        int bookID = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Press 1 or 2 to edit.");
        System.out.println("1: Edit title");
        System.out.println("2: Edit author");
        System.out.print("Enter option: ");
        int editOption = sc.nextInt();

        // Switch statement which will handle editing book
        switch(editOption){
        case 1: 
            // New title
            System.out.print("Enter new title: ");
            String newTitle = sc.nextLine();
            sc.next();

            // Updates title
            newBook.get(position).setTitle(newTitle);

            // Prints out title
            System.out.println(newBook.get(position).getTitle());

            break; // Edit title
```

Above code is only partial, and anything below this is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Use a `Map`, keyed to the `bookId` or you could use Java 8's new `Stream` API and `filter` the `List`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34081193/get-some-value-from-listobject-java/34081295#34081295), but using a `Map` is more efficent

Comment: `int editOption = sc.nextInt(); ... String newTitle = sc.nextLine();` -> [Skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods) (I didn't read your question but this problem needs correction).

Comment: Sorry, I am unsure what the `Map` does. I am still a first year student.

Comment: Do you know what a tree data structure is?  It's kind of similar, it allows for quicker look up items based on a unique key. See [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Comment: A way you may be more familiar with is creating a method with an int parameter (int bookId). You can use a for/for-each loop that returns the object/index if `newBook.getId() == bookId`, otherwise returns null or -1 upon completion of the loop. `Map`, as pointed out however, is more efficient and it's definitely worth familiarizing yourself with even if you don't yet feel comfortable enough to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Direct Approach...

All this does it loops through the `List` of `Book`s and compares the `bookID` entered by the user against the `bookID` of the book.  If a match is found, then the `Book` reference is maintained in the variable `bookToEdit`.

If, after the loop is completed, `bookToEdit` is `null` then there is no matching `Book` in the `List` with the specified ID, otherwise, you now have a reference to the book which needs to be edited

```
// Get which part, and book the user would like to edits
System.out.print("Enter Book ID to begin editing: ");
int bookID = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();
Book bookToEdit = null;
for (Book book : newBook) {
    if (book.getId() == bookID) {
        bookToEdit = book;
        break;
    }
}
if (bookToEdit != null) {

    System.out.println("Press 1 or 2 to edit.");
    System.out.println("1: Edit title");
    System.out.println("2: Edit author");
    System.out.print("Enter option: ");
    int editOption = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();

    if (editOption == 1 || editOption == 2) {
        System.out.print("New " + (editOption == 1 ? "title: " : "author: "));
        String value = sc.nextLine();
        switch (editOption) {
            case 1:
                // Update title
                break;
            case 2:
                // Update author
                break;
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid edit option");
    }

} else {
    System.out.println("Book with the id of " + bookID + " does not exist");
}
```

## `Stream`s

If you want to do something a little more fancy, you could use...

```
// Get which part, and book the user would like to edits
System.out.print("Enter Book ID to begin editing: ");
int bookID = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();

List<Book> filtered = newBook.stream().filter((Book t) -> t.getId() == bookID).collect(Collectors.toList());
if (!filtered.isEmpty()) {
    Book bookToEdit = filtered.get(0);
```

Now, you need to know, this is less efficent then the previous loop, in the fact that it will loop through the entire `List` of `newBook` and will return ALL the books which match the `bookId` (there should realistically only be one)

## `Map`

The most efficient method would be to maintain the `Book`s in a `Map`, rather then a `List`, keyed to the `bookId`.  This way, when required, you could simply look up the book by it's id

```
Map<Integer, Book> newBook = new HashMap<>();
//...
newBook.put(1, new Book(1, "Star Wars", "Somebody"));
newBook.put(2, new Book(2, "Harry Potter", "Somebody else"));
//...

// Get which part, and book the user would like to edits
System.out.print("Enter Book ID to begin editing: ");
int bookID = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();

if (newBook.containsKey(bookID)) {
    Book bookToEdit = newBook.get(bookID);
```

Conceptually, all this is doing is generating a mapping or relationship between the key and the object, this makes it quicker and simpler to find an object based on the supplied key

Have a look at [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Please use a Map to solve your problem. 
You can visit:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_map_interface.htm.

Here are some example code provided for you:

```
    //init the map
    Map<String, Book> dataMap = Maps.newHashMap();


    //insert record
    dataMap.put(bookId, book);


    //update record
    Optional<Book> bookOpt = Optional.ofNullable(dataMap.get(bookId));
    bookOpt.ifPresent(book->{
        book.setTitle(newTitle);
    });
```