# how to remove and search an object by name from linked list in java

Tags: java, object, linked-list

I can write the function to delete at position I choose. But I have problems when I write the function to delete the employee by input of the employee's name. I still have the same problem with the search function. Use case 7, 8 in menu to perform delete and search function. Can anybody help me with my code?

Here's my source code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.Serializable;


/*  Class Node  */

class Employee implements Serializable{
    int ID;
    String name;
    String address;

    Employee(int emp_ID, String emp_name, String emp_address){
        ID = emp_ID;
        name = emp_name;
        address = emp_address;
    }
    public void print(){
        System.out.println(ID);
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(address);

    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ID + "-" + name + "-" + address;
     } 
}

class Node 
{
    protected Employee emp;
    protected Node link;
    public Object name;
    public Node in;

    /*  Constructor  */
    public Node()
    {
        link = null;
        emp = null;
    }    
    /*  Constructor  */
    public Node(Employee e,Node n)
    {
        emp = e;
        link = n;
    }    
    /*  Function to set link to next Node  */
    public void setLink(Node n)
    {
        link = n;
    }    
    /*  Function to set data to current Node  */
    public void setData(Employee e)
    {
        emp = e;
    }    
    /*  Function to get link to next node  */
    public Node getLink()
    {
        return link;
    }    
    /*  Function to get data from current Node  */
    public Employee getData()
    {
        emp.print();
        return null;

    }
}



/* Class linkedList */
class linkedList
{
    protected Node start ;
    protected Node end ;
    public int size ;

    /* Constructor */
    public linkedList()
    {
        start = null;
        end = null;
        size = 0;
    }
    /* Function to check if list is empty */

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return start == null;
    }
    /* Function to get size of the list */
    public int getSize()
    {
        return size;
    }
    /* Function to insert element at the begining */
    public void insertAtStart(Employee e)
    {
        Node nptr = new Node(e,null);    
        nptr.setLink(start);
        if(start == null)
        {            
            start = nptr;
            nptr.setLink(start);
            end = start;            
        }
        else
        {
            end.setLink(nptr);
            start = nptr;        
        }
        size++ ;
    }
    /* Function to insert element at end */
    public void insertAtEnd(Employee e)
    {
        Node nptr = new Node(e,null);    
        nptr.setLink(start);
        if(start == null)
        {            
            start = nptr;
            nptr.setLink(start);
            end = start;            
        }
        else
        {
            end.setLink(nptr);
            end = nptr;            
        }
        size++ ;
    }

    /* Function to insert element at position */
    public void insertAtPos(Employee e , int pos) 
    {
        Node nptr = new Node(e,null);                
        Node ptr = start;
        pos = pos - 1 ;
        for (int i = 1; i < size - 1; i++) 
        {
            if (i == pos) 
            {
                Node tmp = ptr.getLink() ;
                ptr.setLink( nptr );
                nptr.setLink(tmp);
                break;
            }
            ptr = ptr.getLink();
        }
        size++ ;
    }

    /* Function to delete element at position */

    public void searchByName(){

    }

    public void deleteByName(){

    }

    public void deleteAtPos(int pos)
    {    
        if (size == 1 && pos == 1)
        {
            start = null;
            end = null;
            size = 0;
            return ;
        }        
        if (pos == 1) 
        {
            start = start.getLink();
            end.setLink(start);
            size--; 
            return ;
        }
        if (pos == size) 
        {
            Node s = start;
            Node t = start;
            while (s != end)
            {
                t = s;
                s = s.getLink();
            }
            end = t;
            end.setLink(start);
            size --;
            return;
        }
        Node ptr = start;
        pos = pos - 1 ;
        for (int i = 1; i < size - 1; i++) 
        {
            if (i == pos) 
            {
                Node tmp = ptr.getLink();
                tmp = tmp.getLink();
                ptr.setLink(tmp);
                break;
            }
            ptr = ptr.getLink();
        }
        size-- ;
    }

    /* Function to display contents */
    public void display()
    {
       System.out.print("\nEmployee Management= ");
        Node ptr = start;
        if (size == 0) 
        {
            System.out.print("empty\n");
            return;
        }
        if (start.getLink() == start) 
        {
            System.out.print(start.getData()+ "\n");
            return;
        }
        System.out.print(start.getData()+ "" + "\n");
        ptr = start.getLink();
        while (ptr.getLink() != start) 
        {
            System.out.print(ptr.getData()+ "" + "\n");
            ptr = ptr.getLink();
        }

        System.out.print(ptr.getData()+ "\n");
    }
}



/* Class CircularSinglyLinkedList */
public class CurrilarLinkedList
{    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {    


        int ID = 0;
        String name = null;
        String address = null;
        Employee emp = null;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        /* Creating object of linkedList */
        linkedList list = new linkedList(); 
        System.out.println("Circular Singly Linked List Test\n");          
        char ch;
        /*  Perform list operations  */
        do
        {
            System.out.println("\nCircular Singly Linked List Operations\n");
            System.out.println("1. insert at begining");
            System.out.println("2. insert at end");
            System.out.println("3. insert at position");
            System.out.println("4. delete at position");
            System.out.println("5. check empty");
            System.out.println("6. get size");
            System.out.println("7. delete by name");
            System.out.println("8. search by name");
            int choice = scan.nextInt(); 

            switch (choice)
            {
            case 1 : 
                System.out.print("Please input an Employee \n");
                Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Please input an Employee ID");
                ID = myScanner.nextInt();
                myScanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please input an Employee Name");
                name = myScanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please input an Employee Address");
                address = myScanner.nextLine();
                emp = new Employee(ID,name,address);
                list.insertAtStart(emp);                     
                break;                          
            case 2 : 
                System.out.print("Please input an Employee \n");
                myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Please input an Employee ID");
                ID = myScanner.nextInt();
                myScanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please input an Employee Name");
                name = myScanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please input an Employee Address");
                address = myScanner.nextLine();
                emp = new Employee(ID,name,address);
                list.insertAtEnd(emp);                       
                break;                         
            case 3 : 
                System.out.println("Enter position");
                int pos = scan.nextInt() ;
                System.out.print("Please input an Employee \n");
                myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Please input an Employee ID");
                ID = myScanner.nextInt();
                myScanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please input an Employee Name");
                name = myScanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please input an Employee Address");
                address = myScanner.nextLine();
                emp = new Employee(ID,name,address);

                if (pos <= 1 || pos > list.getSize() )
                    System.out.println("Invalid position\n");
                else

                    list.insertAtPos(emp, pos);
                break;                                          
            case 4 : 
                System.out.println("Enter position");
                int p = scan.nextInt() ;
                if (p < 1 || p > list.getSize() )
                    System.out.println("Invalid position\n");
                else
                    list.deleteAtPos(p);
                break;
            case 5 : 
                list.isEmpty();

            case 6 : 
                System.out.println("Size = "+ list.getSize() +" \n");
                break;   
            case 7:
                System.out.println("Enter the name of employee you want to delete:");
                myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                name = myScanner.nextLine();

            case 8:
                System.out.println("Enter the name of employee you want to search:");
                myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                name = myScanner.nextLine();

            default : 
                System.out.println("Wrong Entry \n ");
                break;   
            }


            /*  Display List  */ 
            list.display();
            System.out.println("\nDo you want to continue (Type y or n) \n");
            ch = scan.next().charAt(0);            
        } while (ch == 'Y'|| ch == 'y');                    
    }

}
```

Comment: Please, create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Currently there's a mess of code which is hardly analyzable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java List.contains(Object with field value equal to x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852059/java-list-containsobject-with-field-value-equal-to-x)