# Why arrayList.contains() returns false for this usecase where as System.out.print() writes same on console?

Tags: java, arraylist

Why arrayList.contains() returns false for this usecase where as System.out.print() writes same on console ?

```
ArrayList<Float> random = new ArrayList<Float>();
        random.add(2f);
        random.add(4f);
        random.add(5f);
        random.add(10f);
        random.add(99.9f);
System.out.println(random.contains(5.0)); -- this returns false
```

Where as,

```
System.out.println(random.get(2)); -- this returns 5.0
```

Comment: Maybe try casting the 5.0 in the `contains` to `float`?

Comment: It's because `new Float(5f).equals(5.0) == false`.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, a literal decimal is a `double`, ie `5.0` is a `double`.

The `contains()` method expects an `Object` (not a [primitive](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), such as `double`), so Java [*autoboxes*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) the `double` to a [`Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html) wrapper object, so your test is as if you have coded this:

```
System.out.println(random.contains(new Double(5.0))); -- always false
```

Because they are different types, a `Double` is never going to be equal to a `Float`, so it's always going to be `false`.

However, you can code a literal `float`, add an `F` (or an `f`) after the literal.

Try this:

```
System.out.println(random.contains(5.0F));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you are comparing two floats with doubles, 5.0 is a double. But could also be two different references. In which case this discussion may help you: [Java List.contains(Object with field value equal to x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852059/java-list-containsobject-with-field-value-equal-to-x)