# implementing sort and search methods for arraylist of objects in Java

Tags: java, sorting, search, arraylist, collections

I know basic programming but I'm new to OOP and Java. I'm trying to short and search ArrayList of objects. I know there are many ways to do it but I like two-approach here with collections,
[Java List.contains(Object with field value equal to x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852059/) and here [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/)
codes are working when they are inside the main class but I wanted to move them in student class and calling over my own sort and search methods. The sort function still works but the search returns wrong index integers. I couldn't find what I m missing. The complete code is below.

```
  /* implementation of binary search found at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852059/
and sort solution at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/
 */

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    static ArrayList<Student> course = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter name to search: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String stName = input.nextLine();

        course.add(new Student("will", 353429, 13.2));
        course.add(new Student("joe", 353430, 12.1));
        course.add(new Student("bill", 353431, 14.9));
        course.add(new Student("jim", 353432, 15.3));
        course.add(new Student("jack", 353473, 11.2));
        course.add(new Student("jean", 353439, 16.8));
        course.add(new Student("jill", 353333, 14.9));
        course.add(new Student("jane", 353432, 15.7));
        course.add(new Student("john", 353421, 10.6));
        course.add(new Student("ben", 353438, 16.0));
        course.add(new Student("dave", 353529, 14.9));
        course.add(new Student("jim", 352989, 15.3));
        course.add(new Student("doug", 353178, 11.2));

        sortStudents();

/*  // search part works when its here , inside main class
        int idx = Collections.binarySearch(course, new Student( stName ), new Comparator<Student>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
                return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            }
        });
*/

        int idx = searchStudent( stName );

        System.out.println("Sorted list");
        for (int cnt=0;cnt<course.size();cnt++){
            System.out.println(cnt + " "+ course.get(cnt).toString());
        }

        if (idx>0){
            System.out.println(stName +" found on line: " + idx);
            }else{
            System.out.println(" Not in the list" +idx);
        }
    }

    static void sortStudents(){
        Collections.sort(course,Student.sortByName);
    }

    static int searchStudent(String nm){
        return Collections.binarySearch(course, new Student(nm));
    }


    static  class Student implements Comparable<Student>{
        private String name;
        private int age;
        private double points;

        public Student(String nm) {  this.name = nm; } // constructor

        public Student(String nm, int n, double p) {  // constructor
            this.name = nm;
            this.age = n;
            this.points = p;  }

        public String getName(){ return name; }
// but search code fails when moved here 
        public static Comparator<Student> binarySearch = new Comparator<Student>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
                return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            }
        };

        public static Comparator<Student> sortByName = new Comparator<Student>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Student obj1, Student obj2) {
                //sort in ascending order
                return obj1.name.compareTo(obj2.name);
                //sort in descending order
                //return obj2.name.compareTo(obj1.name);
            }
        };

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Student o) {
            return 0;
        }

        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Name:" + name + ", Age:" + age;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem

That's because  of your `compareTo`, because you didn't implement how may be compared the `Student` between them, you only implemented a name `comparator`, and this is used by the `Collections.binarySearch`

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Student o) {
    return 0;
}
```

You could **fix** with explicit `Comparator`

```
static int searchStudent(String nm) {
    return Collections.binarySearch(course, new Student(nm), Student.sortByName);
}
```

---

#### Improve

Also `Comparator<Student> binarySearch` is same as `Comparator<Student> sortByName`, no reason to get 2 things doing same.

You need to understand that, either

- you need to a `Comparator` to tell how to order objects
- make the object `Comparable` so it knows ITSELF how to order it with the others

Here you did both, that isn't useful, remove the `Comparator`s definitions

---

#### Fix

So only a `compareTo` method will do the job

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Student o) {
    int diff = this.name.compareTo(o.name);
    if (diff != 0) {
        return diff;
    }
    return Integer.compare(this.age, o.age);
}
```

It can be simplified with a `Comparator` that allows some method chaining. Note that it is `private`, it shouldn't be used outside the class manually, AS the class now knows by **itself** how to order elements

```
static private Comparator<Student> studComp = Comparator.comparing(Student::getName)
                                                    .thenComparing(Student::getAge);

@Override
public int compareTo(Student o) {
    return studComp.compare(this, o);
}
```

---

Giving in the main class

```
static void sortStudents() {
    course.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
}

static int searchStudent(String nm) {
    return Collections.binarySearch(course, new Student(nm));
}
```